# In a xcode project that uses swift, but there are functions in swift that I want c++ to call from? Can this be done?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, macos, bridging-header

I'm no stranger to C++ but completely new to swift. But I want to make applications for the iOS platform and possibly for macOS too. But the thing is, and xcode project is entirely in swift, not Objective-C. There is a c++ application that has no wrappers or whatsoever. What I want to achieve is from C++, I want to call out some functions that are in swift and have that function from swift to run in c++. Is this possible or no?

Comment: C++ interop is in the works, but it won't be ready for a while. You'll need to make bridge interfaces in Objective-C(++) or C, and then call those from your Swift code.

Comment: The C++ will he interfering with the Swift but not trying to access any c++ code from swift is what I meant

Comment: Your description is unclear and unspecific. Anyway the general approach for calling a Swift code from a C++ module is to create a wrapper Objective C++ module(*.mm) that calls a Swift module(with ```@objc``` attributes) and exposes a C/C++ interface.

Comment: Ok so I need to make a .mm file for c++ to call a swift function?